# Velocity Template not able to parse and display data in html format

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail, velocity, apache-velocity

I have a simple email program written in `Java` and `Spring` with `Velocity` template to format data that sends email which should be displayed in `html` format. However, it just displays the data along with the `html` tags embedded in it without actually parsing them.

Am I missing anything here?

**EmailService.java**

```
public class EmailService {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(EmailService.class);
    private static final String EMAIL_SUBJECT = ":: Risk Assessment Job Summary Results::";
    private final MailSender mailSender;
    private final String emailRecipientAddress;
    private final String emailSenderAddress;
    private static final String ERROR_MSG = "Error while sending notification email";
    private final TemplateFactory velocityTemplateFactory;
    private Template riskAssessmentJobResultSummaryTemplate;

    public EmailService(MailSender mailSender, String emailRecipientAddress,
            String emailSenderAddress, TemplateFactory velocityTemplateFactory) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
        this.emailRecipientAddress = emailRecipientAddress;
        this.emailSenderAddress = emailSenderAddress;
        this.velocityTemplateFactory = velocityTemplateFactory;
    }

    public void notify(String messageBody) {
        JavaMailSender javaMailSender = (JavaMailSender)mailSender;
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
        try {
            mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(getHostname() + " - " + EMAIL_SUBJECT);
            mimeMessageHelper.setTo(emailRecipientAddress);
            mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(emailSenderAddress);
            mimeMessageHelper.setText(getEmailContent(messageBody));
            javaMailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MailException e) {
            throw new EmailSendException(ERROR_MSG, e);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getHostname() {
        try {
            return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            return "unknown host";
        }
    }

    private String getEmailContent(String messageBody) {
        try {
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            this.riskAssessmentJobResultSummaryTemplate =
                    velocityTemplateFactory.create("velocity/risk-assessment-job-results-summary.vm");
            VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
            velocityContext.put("hostname", getHostname());
            velocityContext.put("messageBody", messageBody);
            this.riskAssessmentJobResultSummaryTemplate.merge(velocityContext, stringWriter);
            return stringWriter.toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.error("Unable to read the email template", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**risk-assessment-job-results-summary.vm**

```
<h3>Summary report for Risk Assessment Job on ${hostname}:</h3>
<table style="border:none;">
    <tr><td>${messageBody}</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Actual Email Output:**

```
<h3>Summary report for Risk Assessment Job on KOP-DBT0J12:</h3> 
<table style="border:none;">
<tr><td>
TotalTxPending: 0
TotalTxAccepted: 0
TotalTxRejected: 0
TotalTxProcessed: 0
</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Expected Email Output:**

```
Summary report for Risk Assessment Job on KOP-DBT0J12:
TotalTxPending: 0
TotalTxAccepted: 0
TotalTxRejected: 0
TotalTxProcessed: 0
```

Comment: Have you tried to send that string to email? as i think your program works very fine and that string is pretty good to send email

Comment: Email sending works !  The problem is the content in that email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the content as html

```
 message.setContent(getEmailContent(messageBody), "text/html; charset=utf-8")
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the smoking gun :)

This one line change fixed the problem. Here the `true` flag denotes the content type is `html` in the email body.

```
mimeMessageHelper.setText(getEmailContent(messageBody), true);
```

Answer (score -1):

this should be the answer

```
mimeMessageHelper.setContent(someHtmlMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: want to know the reason for downvoting?

Comment: Your proposed solution won't solve this problem. The change is required in the java code and not in the template.

Comment: ahh! there you go. I was too fast to not to think about that. I just looked at my program and compared your template with mine and thought this could be the mistake.

Comment: please look at [answer]